# Sum of independent continuous and discrete random variables

Tags: statistics, random-variables

I am trying to understand how to create a PDF from the sum of an independent continuous and discrete rv, *Z = X + Y*. I was wondering if anyone would be willing to provide an example of this. I have seen the equation *FZ(z) = ∑ FY(z−x) . PX(x)*, but I can't seem to make sense of how the z's and x's are taken as input into FY. Specifically I am working with a Bernoulli and Gaussian, but an example with any continuous and discrete random variables would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ has density $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(y-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ and independently $X$ has $\mathbb P(X=1)=p$ and $\mathbb P(X=0)=1-p$, then $Z=X+Y$ has density  $$(1-p) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(z-0-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)} + p \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sigma} e^{-(z-1-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}$$  and you can see that this is $f_Z(z)=\sum\limits_x \mathbb P(X=x) f_Y(z-x)$

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation, I was getting confused at some of the notation, but this makes it much clearer - thank you.